# How to force a cleanup job on SQL Server Express

Tags: sql-server, azure-devops, sql-server-express

So I'm using SQL Server as Azure DevOps database and there's a 10 GB limit which I didn't know and is now reached. So the obvious solution is to use a proper SQL Server instead - I know.
However for now (this is an emergency) I need a quick and dirty solution, so I deleted a bunch of stuff in Azure DevOps, but it has no effect. Is there a way in SQL Server Express to force the cleanup job that presumably runs once a day so that some memory is freed?

Comment: Have you seen this? https://www.marcusfelling.com/blog/2020/how-to-reduce-the-size-of-your-tfs-azure-devops-server-collection-databases/

Comment: No I haven't, but I'll try it. Thanks!

Comment: Happy to help. Please let me know if that works and I'll make my comment the answer.